# Channel Live Streaming

Tags: java, android, live, rtsp, hlsl

Pleaaase its so critical can any one help me to stream this url :

i tried this : http://new.islamahmadiyya.net/live-no-links.html

and the same but with rtsp : rtsp://mtaintl.mpl.miisolutions.net:1935/mtaintl-live-1/*definst*/mp4:MTA3_300k.stream

i tied every code in google but the same result not working .

can anyone know if the url it wrong ? , i can call the channel and tell them to change the format

pleas again , i count on stackoverflow

```
Uri stream = Uri.parse("rtsp://mtaintl.mpl.miisolutions.net:1935/mtaintl-live-1/_definst_/mp4:MTA3_300k.stream"); 
    Intent videointent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,stream); 
    startActivity(videointent);
```

second way :

```
String LINK = "rtsp://mtaintl.mpl.miisolutions.net:1935/mtaintl-live-1/_definst_/mp4:MTA3_300k.stream";
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();*/
```

another one :

```
vv = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.video);
    //Uri videoUri =
    //Uri.parse("rtsp://mtaintl.mpl.miisolutions.net:1935/mtaintl-live-1/_definst_/mp4:MTA3_300k.stream");
    //vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    //vv.setVideoURI(videoUri);
    //vv.start();

    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    vv.setMediaController(mc);

    //Set the path of Video or URI
    vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov"));
    //

  //Set the focus
    vv.requestFocus();
```

and this

```
 String LINK = "rtsp://mtaintl.mpl.miisolutions.net:1935/mtaintl-live-1/_definst_/mp4:MTA3_300k.stream";
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();
```

Comment: Slow down. Take a step back. What's the problem you're having?  Right now all I see is that you can't get something to stream.  Do you have the code you're using to try to stream it? If so; share it with us.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker i added the code i tried , but all with the same result can't play this video

Comment: What language is this? What Framework? What error do you get? Does anything show up in the JavaScript console for Chrome?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker this is java for android write it via eclipse ,